# Call test suite property within the request in SoapUi

Tags: groovy, properties, soapui, test-suite

all

I am using free version of SoapUI. 
What I have is a test suite with many test cases. In each test case there is a request where I need to specify a date. So I want to create a general script for all cases and just call the result of it in each request I need.

What I do:
1. I have test suite SaveOperation where in SetupScript window at the bottom I write script:

```
def sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
def windowClosed = sdf.format(new Date()-20) 
log.info(windowClosed)
```

2. In this test suite I have many test cases as I wrote. So when for example in test case named **SaveValid** I need to specify Date parameter I write the following right in the xml request (in date parameter):

```
${#SaveOperation#windowClosed}
```

But it doesn't work. Could anyone suggest what is wrong with this way?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct approach. `log.info()` will only write the information to a log.

change

```
log.info(windowClosed)
```

to

```
testSuite.setPropertyValue("windowClosed", windowClosed.toString())
```

and then refer to it as:

```
${#TestSuite#windowClosed}
```

Comment: In this row:

`testSuite.setPropertyValue("windowClosed", windowClosed.toString())`

Instead of **"windowClosed"** you mean I need to specify the actual name of parameter in a request?

Comment: No. The code I showed is literal. See `setPropertyValue(String, String)` https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/index.html?com/eviware/soapui/model/TestPropertyHolder.html#setPropertyValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Thank you for such a long delay even though it is quite late ;)